# What are the specific stats of the abilities and Hero weapons?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

The ability descriptions are very short and lacking a lot of additional information. For example when I use the "UNLEASHED" star card I know that my unleash damage at maximum range will increase by up to 50 damage.

That sounds pretty nice, but having no idea how much damage which ability deals at all lets me hardly assume how good this is compared to other cards.

i.e. in arcade mode with AI having double health and only playing against heavies without that card being equipped I'm one-hitting everyone. On the one hand, if that's not any additional special condition it would let me assume that unleash deals over 400 damage uncharged on the other hand that would mean I can easily 2-hit villains with unleash, which I never felt like I could.

So, can anyone tell me what are the numbers of the abilities? (range/radius/damage/active times/casting times/status applied/any additional notes with numbers)

And, in the same way, the specifics of each hero's weapon (animation time/damage per animation/stamina drain when attacking or blocking/their stamina pool/eventually AoE range, time they apply struggle or other effects and their movement pattern + any additional notes).

Comment: Would this be more on topic if I asked for the stats of the abilitys in specific? I phrased it this way, as I thought asking for the specific stats of each ability might end being too broad. Feedback is welcomed :)

Comment: Actually, asking for the stats of each ability would probably be fine.  It's too broad if there are too many possible answers, not if the one answer is too big.  One complete answer would be a very nice resource for other people to look at later.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Hero stats spreadsheet]

The most detailed spreadsheet I could find was posted by the user *anidriX* [in this thread](https://battlefront-forums.ea.com/discussion/127303/hero-villain-stats) and includes the most recent June 11th balance changes.